# Best way to handle view and helper-only constants in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, constants, dry, helper

I have a constant that is only used in views, but it's used in different ways in different places.  It's an array of option names, and is used for select boxes, but I also use this in other views to see if strings are found in this array, and respond accordingly.

What's the best way to handle this to keep DRY?

I initially created a constant in a helper, but that doesn't seem to be accessible in the views.

I've since switched to creating a method in a helper, that does nothing except return the constant.  However, this really seems to be against the spirit of Rails, since now essentially I'm using a lower-cased constant.

I could of course stick it in a model, but it's really got nothing to do with any of the models.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can define constants in helpers, but you will need to refer to them by their fully qualified name in your views.

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  MyConstant = "something"
end
```

In any view:

```
<%= ApplicationHelper::MyConstant %>
```

Comment: In controllers/models you can do `include ApplicationHelper`, to avoid typing it. You can't do it inside views though, can you? :/

Comment: It turns out whatever modules you `include` in the controller is available to views.

Comment: You can also write a method in the helper to refer to it so you don't have to repeat the helper name in the view.

Answer (score 4):

Put it in `config/initializers/constants.rb` and it will be availble everywhere.

Comment: Seems kind of unfortunate to add a global constant when it will only ever be used in views and helpers, I'm not sure that's better than just using a method to alias it.

Comment: FYI - this is no longer the case in rails 4 production mode - templates live in a different namespace and need to access constants via ApplicationController:CONSTANT_NAME